# Separability of field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I'm trying to figure out if these statements are equivalent for an arbitrary field extension $L/k$, such that $\text{char} (k) = p$ and $A$ is a reduced commutative $k$-algebra.

$1)$ $L/k$ is separable (it has a separating transcendence basis).

$2)$ $L \otimes_k k^{p^{-1}}$ is reduced, an integral domain or a field.

$3)$ $L \otimes_k k^{p^{-r}}$ is reduced, an integral domain or a field for each $r = 0, 1, ..., \infty$.

$4)$ $A \otimes_k L$ is reduced.

$5)$ $A \otimes_k L$ is semisimple.

$6)$ $L\otimes_k F$ is reduced for all field extensions $F$ of $k$.

$7)$ $L \otimes_k F$ is semisimple for all field extensions $F$ of $k$.

I proved $1)$ implies $3)$. Furthermore, in $4$ and $5$, I'm trying to make an analogy between perfect fields and separable field extensions.

Thanks in advance.